# Restrict Javascript Rotation Angle (With Propeller.js)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to use propeller.js to restrict the rotation angle of an image. As of right now, if I spin my image twice, my output would read 720. I would like to make it so the element’s output will reset to 0 when spun over 360. In addition, I would like it to not output negative angles if I spin counterclockwise. For example going from 10 to 280.

Here is a codepen of where I am currently at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyZaXK

```
$('img').propeller({inertia: 1, speed: 10,onRotate: function(){ console.log(this.angle); }});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Using a Modulo made this work the way I wanted!

Here’s what I added:

```
(degrees + 360) % 360
```

Which resulted in:

```
$('img').propeller({inertia: 1, speed: 10,onRotate: function(){ console.log((this.angle + 360) % 360); }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looked in the Propeller.js source, found another solution. You can set zero angle if 360 is reached:

```js
onRotate: function(){ 
  if(this.angle===360) 
  {
    this.virtualAngle = 0;
  }
  console.log(this.angle);
}
```

Comment: I like this better than the answer I found! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of the `normalizeAngle()` method of Propeller itself:

```
onRotate: function () {
    console.log(this.normalizeAngle(this.angle));
}
```

That also avoids negative angles.